# PHP Subsituting FOREACH with EACH in a die() loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, each

Hey guys I'm working on a chunk of my function and trying to keep it a little cleaner

I was trying to use `if(each($ar['error']!=0))` intead of running this through a `FOREACH`
loop but can't get it to work right. Maybe a second set of eyes on this, and some other thoughts?

This is how it is currently

```
foreach($ar['error'] as $err) {
    if($err!=0) { 
        switch($err) {
            case 1: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-ini-max']);     exit; break;
            case 2: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-maxsize']);     exit; break;
            case 3: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-partial']);     exit; break;
            case 4: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-no-file']);     exit; break;
            case 6: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-no-tmpDir']);   exit; break;
            case 7: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-cant-write']);  exit; break;
            case 8: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-ext']);         exit; break;
        }
    }
}
```

and I was trying to do something along the lines of

```
include('class/debug.class.php');
$ar['error'][3]=1;

    if($ar['error']['value']!=0) { 
        switch($ar['error']['value']) {
            case 1: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-ini-max']);     exit; break;
            case 2: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-maxsize']);     exit; break;
            case 3: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-partial']);     exit; break;
            case 4: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-no-file']);     exit; break;
            case 6: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-no-tmpDir']);   exit; break;
            case 7: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-cant-write']);  exit; break;
            case 8: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-ext']);         exit; break;
        }
    }

debug($ar);

//debug
'error' => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0,
    5 => 0,
    6 => 0,
    7 => 0,
),
```

But it seems like it never catches the `1`?

Comment: You set `$ar['error'][3]=1;` but check `if($ar['error']['value']!=0)` - did you mean `$ar['error']['value']=1;`

Comment: no `EACH` returns in k/v pairs `print_r(each($ar['error']));` produces `Array ( [1] => 0 [value] => 0 [0] => 0 [key] => 0 ) `

Comment: I'm not sure I am following. The second script won't loop through anything. Also using each will remove the error details from the array so that they cannot be logged later on your error catching callbacks (if you have any).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, if you post a Answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are traversing an array with `each()` this is typically done in combination with the `list()` function within a while loop. So if you are trying to avoid the `foreach()` loop, this is the other possibility.

```
while(list($key, $val) = each($arr)) {
   ...
}
```

Check out the documentation for `each()`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes: 
Your arrays and your conditional statements don't line up.
`$ar['error']` has been populated with 7 values.
Only one of the 7 is "true" -> 1, the rest are zeros.
You need a foreach statement

```
foreach($array['error'] as $errorTest){
   switch($errorTest) {
      case 1: $this->doDie($this->errors['upl-ini-max']);     exit; break;
```

etc.

Your code shows that you are testing of `$ar['error']['value']`.
This variable doesn't appear to exist, so your switch test will fail.

Since you have inserted the error value in an array -- for some reason not obvious -- you will need to `each` through all the elements of the array.

FYI, since your are populating $ar['error'][3]=1`, my corrected switch statement above would always break with case 1 (errors['upl-ini-max']).

But my guess is that what you REALLY want is for it to break at case 3.

Consider whether an error **array** is needed here. The simpler solution would be the place the error code in a single variable 
`$errorCode=3`, and switch on that variable.

```
$errorCode=3;
switch($errorCode){
  case 1: dosomething(1); break;
```

By testing a variable instead of an array, since you aren't `each`-ing through an array, you won't need the `exit; break`, construct in your example code. You can simply `break;`.

Comment: Nemo, this is to old to switch the accept but plus one for posting this answer. Thanks and much appreciate for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

`$ar['error']` appears to be an array. You can't expect `switch($ar['error'])` to match any of your case statements, which are integers. You have to `switch` based on a scalar value.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: PHP actually allows you to switch on a string

Comment: @SamHeuck Yes, that's what I said. [Scalar values](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php) include strings.

Answer (score 0):

i dont quit understand what you're trying to do here, but if you're trying to check if the array is empty you could just use an if(empty($arrayName))

like so:

```
if(empty($yourArray))
{echo"<p>There's nothing in the array.....</p>";}
else
{
foreach ($yourArray as $current_array_item)
{
//do something with the current array item here
} 
}
```